# Text Object for HTML/XML attributes, e.g. data-foo="bar baz caz"

Tags: filetype-html, custom-text-object

Is there a plugin or a way to work with HTML text objects, e.g.

Say the cursor is in one of the attributes below:

```html
<div data-foo="bar baz caz" class="a b c">
```

I wish to treat `data-foo="bar baz caz"` or `class="a b c"` as text objects, e.g. change inner attribute group, or change a attribute group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [vim-textobj-xmlattr](https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-textobj-xmlattr) plugin does exactly that.

> This vim plugin provides two text objects: ax and ix.
> They represent XML/HTML attributes.

> `ix` works with the inner attribute, with no surrounding whitespace. `ax` works like `aw` does: it includes the whitespace before the attribute. I know that `aw` includes the whitespace after/before or whatever it finds more fitty, but XML/HTML attributes always include whitespace before them, while they do not always include whitespace after.

Comment: GAME CHANGER!!! Most awesomeness!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you kind sir!